# Limit of matrix $A$ raised to power of $n$, as $n$ approaches infinity.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, limits

I understand that the limit of $n$ approaching infinity of a matrix $A^n$, can be computed, in some cases, by looking at the diagonalization of that matrix, and then looking at the limit of $n$ going to infinity of the resulting diagonal matrix, $D$, whose elements are raised to the power $n$.

What I do not understand is when we do not raise the matrix, call it $P$, consisting of the eigenvectors of $A$, and its inverse, to the power of $n$ as well?

So:

$ P^{-1}AP = D    $

$A = PDP^{-1}  $

$A^n = (PDP^{-1})^n$

$A^n = P^nD^n(P^{-1})^n$

Why do the matrices $P^n$ and $(P^{-1})^n$ not have to be taken into account when looking at the limit of $n$ going to infinity?

Answer (score 26):

In general, the statement
$$
(AB)^n=A^nB^n
$$
is false for square matrices. So it's not true in general that, from $A=PDP^{-1}$ it follows that $A^n=P^nD^n(P^{-1})^n$.

Rather you should note that
$$
A^2=(PDP^{-1})(PDP^{-1})=PDP^{-1}PDP^{-1}=PDDP^{-1}=PD^2P^{-1}
$$
and, by easy induction,
$$
A^n=PD^nP^{-1}
$$
for every $n$. Do you see the difference?

Now, in order to compute the limit, it is sufficient to compute the limit of $D^n$, because matrix multiplication is continuous.

Comment: Perhaps it is worth remarking that we do still have $P$ and $P^-$ to take into account, but that is straightforward and we do not have to worry what $P^n$ might be.

Comment: @PJTraill Isn't the “Rather” part covering it?

Comment: Formally it certainly does, but given the level of the questioner I thought one might make that explicit (though an alternative would be to nudge them to chew on some thought inclining them in that direction).

Answer (score 13):

We have that

$$A = PDP^{-1}\implies A^2 = PDP^{-1} PDP^{-1}= PD(P^{-1}P)DP^{-1}= PD (I)DP^{-1}=PD^2P^{-1}$$

and so on we can generalize the result rigorously for any $n$ by induction.

Comment: thank you! the "inner" factors on $P$ and $P^{-1}$ will cancel and you'll only be left with the one $P$ and its inverse.

Comment: @Tyna Yes exactly and then we can generalize that for any $n$ (rigoursly by induction).